# Two calls to `seq` in strict version of `first`

Tags: haskell, seq

Why are there two calls to `seq` in the code below ([sourced from here](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/590-Evaluation-State_Assertions_in_Haskell)) - `r` is passed twice:

```
first' :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
first' f (x,y) = let { x' = f x; r = (x', y) } 
                   in x' `seq` r `seq` r
```

I would think that one call to `seq` would do the trick of making it strict.

Comment: I think this is a typo. There's no point in writing ``r `seq` r``, since that is equivalent to `r`.

Comment: @chi really? I think ``x `seq` y`` will only evaluate `x` to HNF without touching `y`

Comment: @Carsten No, that's a common misconception. If the value of ``x `seq` y`` is demanded then `x` is evaluated but `y` is evaluated as well, since we need that to produce the (demanded!) value of the whole expression. If the value of ``x `seq` y`` is not demanded, then neither `x` nor `y` are evaluated (of course). There is no middle ground.

Comment: @chi - yes you are right - sorry

Comment: This is indeed redundant, since `seq r r` always equals `r`. Not only that, but `r` is already in WHNF, so `seq r` is semantically identical to `id` anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a mistake at some level or other. `` r `seq` r `` and `r` are completely identical, semantically.

Answer (score 5):

I'm fairly confident that it is a typo. I guess it should have been

```
first' :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
first' f (x,y) = let { x' = f x; r = (x', y) } 
                   in x' `seq` y `seq` r
```

so that both pair components are forced. Or perhaps

```
first' :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
first' f (x,y) = let { x' = f x; r = (x', y) } 
                   in x' `seq` r
```

which produces a fully evaluated pair, assuming that the second component was already evaluated. This is sensible, for instance, if all the operations we use that act on the `IORef (Int, Int)` state preserve the invariant "both components must always be evaluated".